# How to Receive Chat message from a GTalk client

Tags: c#, xmpp

I need to receive chat message to a C# app from a GTalk client. I already send msg from a c# app to a GTalk client. How i received message from GTalk client. Here is the send message code.

```
agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection objXmpp;

objXmpp = new agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection();
agsXMPP.Jid jid = null;
jid = new agsXMPP.Jid("Email Address");

objXmpp.Port = 5222;
objXmpp.Password = "Password";
objXmpp.Username = jid.User;
objXmpp.ConnectServer = "talk.google.com";
objXmpp.Server = jid.Server;
objXmpp.UseStartTLS = true;

objXmpp.AutoResolveConnectServer = true;
objXmpp.Open();
xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) 
{
    xmpp.Send(new Message("Sending Email Address", 
                          MessageType.chat, 
                          "Hello, how are you?")); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [Smuxi's agsXMPP Fork](https://github.com/meebey/agsxmpp) because you don't specifically say, and looking at the code for the `XmppClientConnection` class, there's an [event in there](https://github.com/meebey/agsxmpp/blob/master/agsxmpp/XmppClientConnection.cs#L577) for receiving messages, `OnMessage`. So it looks like a simple matter of hooking up to that. For example, assuming you have a message handler method like this:

```
private void OnMessageHandler(object sender, Message msg)
{            
    //Do something here
}
```

And hook it up like this:

```
objXmpp.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(OnMessageHandler);
```